# Failed prop type: The prop `location` is marked as required in `PrivateRoute`, but its value is `undefined`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-proptypes

To give access to authenticated users only, I created a component PrivateRoute like described [here](https://github.com/strapi/strapi-examples/tree/57e21644248c66e15c36c840671589178e5a5011/good-old-react-authentication-flow). Everything works fine, but it gives me a warning, that 'location' is undefined.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import auth from '../../hooks/login/auth';

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={(props) => (
      auth.getToken() !== null ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect to={{
          pathname: '/log_in',
          state: { from: props.location },
        }}
        />
      )
    )}
  />
);

PrivateRoute.propTypes = {
  component: PropTypes.any.isRequired, // eslint-disable-line
  location: PropTypes.shape({
    pathname: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  }).isRequired,
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

```
<Switch>
   <Route exact path="/" component={LogIn} />
   <Route exact path="/log_in" component={LogIn} />
   <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
</Switch>
```

If I make a console log in the render method, location is always defined. So wtf?

```
<Route
    {...rest}
    render={(props) => {
      console.log('LOCATION', props.location);
      return auth.getToken() !== null ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect to={{
          pathname: '/log_in',
          state: { from: props.location },
        }}
        />
      );
    }}
  />
```

I have tried to give location a default value, but then the whole page was blank.

```
PrivateRoute.propTypes = {
  component: PropTypes.any.isRequired, // eslint-disable-line
  location: PropTypes.shape({
    pathname: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  }),
};

PrivateRoute.defaultProps = {
   location: {
    pathname: '',
   },
};
```

What is the problem here? And how is it possible that location is undefined when any console log output shows a defined location object?

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

You are declaring a `location` PropType for the `PrivateRoute` component, which will obviously be undefined since you aren't passing a `location` prop to your `PrivateRoute` component when rendering, and you are logging the [route props](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) of the `Route` component that the `PrivateRoute` is rendering.

```
const PrivateRoute = ({
  component: Component,  // <-- not logging any of these props
  ...rest
}) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={(props) => ( // <-- logging these route props
      auth.getToken() !== null ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect to={{
          pathname: '/log_in',
          state: { from: props.location },
        }}
        />
      )
    )}
  />
);
```

`location` is not even a `Route` component prop, it's just one of the props passed to all three render methods (`component`, `render`, and `children` function).

If you want/need to specify that the `location.pathname` prop is available then this should be done on the component that is being rendered by your custom `PrivateRoute` component as this is where a `location` prop is passed. In this case, it is the `Dashboard` component that should have `location.pathname` defined as a required prop.

If it helps, there is a [react-router-prop-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-prop-types) package you can install and use. It exports a `location` PropType [declaration](https://github.com/Prayer-R/react-router-prop-types/blob/master/src/index.ts#L3-L15) with the `pathname` prop already required.

> ```
> export const location = PropTypes.shape({
>   hash: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
>   key: PropTypes.string, // only in createBrowserHistory and createMemoryHistory
>   pathname: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
>   search: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
>   state: PropTypes.oneOfType([
>     PropTypes.array,
>     PropTypes.bool,
>     PropTypes.number,
>     PropTypes.object,
>     PropTypes.string,
>   ]), // only in createBrowserHistory and createMemoryHistory
> });
> ```

In `Dashboard`:

```
import { location } from 'react-router-prop-types';

Dashboard.propTypes = {
  // ... the other prop types
  location: location.isRequired,
};
```